# knockout arraychange - possible status

Tags: knockout.js

Listening to an observable array for changes
ie

```
coll.subscribe(function(changes) {}, null, "arrayChange")
```

Does anyone know what the possible status values could be?

I have seen
"added" & "deleted" 
Are there any others? Is there a reference somewhere?
Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently only `"added"` and `"deleted"` are the possible status values.

However this is not described expicility in the documentation, but you get this info:

- From the [Knockout 3.0 RC announcement](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/10/08/knockout-3-0-release-candidate-available/)
- From reading the [specs for the feature](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/spec/observableArrayChangeTrackingBehaviors.js)
- Or reading the actual source code of the [observableArray.changeTracking](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/observableArray.changeTracking.js)